# Split dataset Cats_vs_dogs to train and val with tf 2.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I tried to split the Cats_vs_dogs dataset with the split function but I cannot check if it worked. when I call the num_example on train_info and val_info I got the same number 23262. why?

```
    dataset, info = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs',
                              split='train',
                              shuffle_files=True,
                              as_supervised=True,
                              with_info=True
                              )                                                                                            
    ds_train, train_info = tfds.load(
                            'cats_vs_dogs',
                            split='train[:80%]',
                            shuffle_files=True,
                            as_supervised=True,
                            with_info=True
                            )
    ds_val, val_info= tfds.load(
                        'cats_vs_dogs',
                        split='train[-20%:]',
                        shuffle_files=True,
                        as_supervised=True,
                        with_info=True
                        )

    print(train_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
    print(train_info.splits['train'].num_shards)
    print(val_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
    print(val_info.splits['train'].num_shards)
```

I got 23262 examples from train_info, info, and val_info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the number of example from each split, we have to ask for
train_info.splits['train[:80%]'].num_examples
and
val_info.splits['train[-20%:]'].num_examples

better for splitting the dataset, using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory worked better for me.